# log de modificaciones en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

mi intención es hacer un log de modificaciones para guardar los cambios que se le hagan a los contenidos de las tablas en la base de datos. En este momento estoy trabajando en el log de modificaciones de las categorías, y tengo:

La tabla `acat` que tiene: `instancia`, `categoria_id`, `actualizado`, `actualizado_por`, `creado`, `creado_por`

A su vez, tengo la tabla `detalles_acat`, que tiene: `fecha`, `campo_mod`, `valor_previo`, `valor_nuevo`, `usuario`, `acat_id`

Tengo el siguiente código en mi función que actualiza las categorías:

```
    public function update(UpdateRequest $request, Categoria $categoria)
{

    $categoria->fill($request->all());

    $old = $categoria->getOriginal();
    $new = $categoria->getDirty();

    $acats = ACAT::where('categoria_id', $categoria->id)->get();

    //OBTENEMOS LOS DATOS DE LA CREACIÓN
    $acat1 = ACAT::where('categoria_id', $categoria->id)->where('instancia', 1)->get();
    $creado_por = $acat1->creado_por;
    if ($creado_por == null) {
        $creado_por = Auth::user()->name;
    }

    //CREAMOS ACAT
    $acat = ACAT::create([
        'instancia' => count($acats) + 1,
        'categoria_id' => $categoria->id,
        'actualizado' => Carbon::now('America/La_Paz'),
        'actualizado_por' => Auth::user()->name,
        'creado' => $categoria->created_at,
        'creado_por' => $creado_por
    ]);

    //CREAMOS LOS DETALLES ACAT
    foreach ($old as $data) {
        $results[] = array("fecha" => Carbon::now('America/La_Paz'),
                           "campo_mod" => "", 
                           "valor_previo" => "", 
                           "valor_nuevo" => "", 
                           "usuario" => Auth::user()->name,
                           "acat_id" => $acat->id,);



    }

        $acat->detalleacat()->createMany($results);

        return redirect()->route('admin.categorias.index')->with('update', 'Se editó correctamente');

}
```

Mi tabla de categoría contiene: `id`, `nombre`, `descripción`, `created_at`, `updated_at`.

Donde tengo dudas es en la parte del `foreach` de la creación de los `detalles_acat`, ya que no sé cómo ingresar lo que es el campo modificado, (que dependiendo de lo que se actualizara sería nombre o descripción), el valor previo y el valor nuevo que se haya ingresado dentro de la variable correspondiente. Usando `getDirty()` y `getOriginal()` me trae los valores viejos y nuevos, la cosa está en que no sé cómo utilizarlos.

Aprecio mucho la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mi solución fue utilizar `getFillable()` explicado en [esta página](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getFillable), donde dice que se usa para:

> Obtener los atributos rellenables para el modelo.

Y quedó así:

```
$fillable = $categoria->getFillable();

foreach ($fillable as $fil) {
            if ($categoria->isDirty($fil)) {
                    $new = $categoria->getDirty($fil);
                    $old = $categoria->getOriginal($fil);
                    $results[] = array("fecha" => Carbon::now('America/La_Paz'),
                                       "campo_mod" => $fil, 
                                       "valor_previo" => $old, 
                                       "valor_nuevo" => $new[$fil], 
                                       "usuario" => Auth::user()->name);
            }
    }

$acat->detalleacat()->createMany($results);
```